# Query not returning distinct JSON column values

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, join, select

I am using `MySql 8.0 verion` and have a `table t1` which looks as below:

```
+--------++--------------------------------------------------+
| id     | type               | users                        | 
+--------+--------------------+------------------------------+
| 11     | ["type1", "type2"] | ["user1", "user2", "user3"]  |
| 12     | ["type2", "type4"] | ["user2", "user22", "user3"] |      
+--------+--------------------+------------------------------+
```

I want to create a query to find all `distinct type` in the table.
I have written the following query but it is returning a blank row:

```
select distinct type
from 
    t1,
    json_table(
        type,
        "$[*]"
        columns (type varchar(50) PATH "$")
    ) t
order by type
```

Query Output:

```
+---------------------+
| type                |
+---------------------+
| ["type1", "type2"]  |
| ["type2", "type4"]  |
+---------------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+--------+
| type   |
+--------+
| type1  |
| type2  |
| type4  |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The column `type` is ambiguous because it appears in both `t1` and in your JSON_TABLE result. You should qualify the column.

```
mysql> select distinct t.type from t1, 
       json_table(type, '$[*]' columns (type varchar(50) PATH '$')) as t 
       order by t.type;
+-------+
| type  |
+-------+
| type1 |
| type2 |
| type4 |
+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the `JSON_TABLE column to "types"`. However, this query is returning one extra row in the end which has all the types such as `["type1", "type2", "type4"]`

Comment: the query is not returning distinct values when Json array has more than one entries

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, it works in my case even if I have duplicate values in one of the arrays.

Comment: I think if there is one more row in the table which has three values `["type1", "type2", "type4"]` then it will return this row too. This way the result will not be unique

Comment: Okay, I don't know what you're doing, but I tested that exact case and I do not get duplicates in my result.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve it by writing a `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT distinct j.type FROM t1
   CROSS JOIN
   JSON_TABLE(t1.type, " $ [*]" 
                COLUMNS ( type VARCHAR(20) PATH '$' )
              ) j
```

Comment: There's no difference between `CROSS JOIN` and the SQL-89 comma-style join.

Comment: Using `CROSS JOIN` is helpful as it not returning each row as an array